# Freezing while creating a new AVD

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

The point is that I want to create a new AVD. Until now, I installed an Android SDK provided by Google inc. Also, I installed features required to create an AVD.

So, I start to create an new AVD.

1. Input a name >> KKOT
2. Select a target >> Android 4.0 - API Level 14
3. Input SD Card Size >> 32
4. Select Skin >> Built-in: Default (WVGA800)
5. Push a button 'Create AVD'

But, as soon as I am on step 5, it freezes.

Environment:

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate K x64 - Kor
- JDK: JDK 7 32 bit

Comment: I don't have permissions of viewing your images.

Comment: fixed the image links but don't forget your magnifying glasses. Btw: @Park you should stop spamming dots (edited and removed) .................... ................. ugly as hell

Comment: Sorry about images. I have leanred to see right now that links is temporary. So, delete links...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use JDK 7 with Android SDK! Please use JDK 5 or JDK 6 (I recommend to use JDK 6).

Comment: Have you had JDK 7 installed? Have you uninstalled it before installing JDK 6?

Comment: To: Yury... No, but I set a default JDK as JDK 6 using setting CLASSPATH values. Now, I'm using multi-JDK, JDK6 and JDK7.

Comment: Maybe this can cause the problems. Try to uninstall jdk 7. I've faced with a lot of different problems with jdk 7.

Comment: To:Yury] Yes. I'll try to do as your suggestion. And appreciate your concern.